# Using replaceAll to get a double

Tags: regex, double, replaceall

I need to extract a double out of a String. The problem is, that the String looks like this:

```
"13,05 €"
```

Now I tried to extract just the number, using regex.

```
Double.parseDouble(test.getAmount().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

As you can see, there is one problem. By using \D+ the ',' also will be replaced and I don't get the correct amount.
Now I thought about how to fix this. Guess I need something like: "Replace all non-digits except comma". But I can't figure out, how to express that with regex.
Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negated character class:

```
Double.parseDouble(test.getAmount().replaceAll("[^\\d,]+", ""));
```

`[^\\d,]` is a negated character class, because it starts with a `^`. So this class matches everything, but digits and commas.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33hmk)